# Double queueing of messages to an Azure Queue from an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have an Azure Function running on a timer trigger that finds a set of records from a datasource and uses that to build up an array of messages and then sends that to a queue output.

The function reports (via `context.log()`) finding 4 records and then building an array of 4 messages for the queue. But the queue gets 8 messages.

I am *not* seeing the function triggered/invoked twice (as far as I can tell... watching logs, etc.). I'm just seeing double entries into the queue.

Basic details:

- Node.js (v12) async function
- Consumption plan (version ~3)
- Runs in less than 1 second
- Sending to queue using `context.bindings.outboundQueue = outgoingMessagesArray`
- Timer trigger has `"useMonitor": false` set (per [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2968))

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Sigh... well now I'm seeing double function invocations. Log looks like this:

```
2021-08-17T14:28:00.011 [Information] Executing 'Functions.sendToQueue' (Reason='Timer fired at 2021-08-17T14:28:00.0112754+00:00', Id=f41c233f-42c9-4da6-ac8a-f354d04be0df)
2021-08-17T14:28:00.012 [Information] Executing 'Functions.sendToQueue' (Reason='Timer fired at 2021-08-17T14:28:00.0117734+00:00', Id=3b0a8941-604e-45b4-839b-33eb5e467751)
2021-08-17T14:28:00.133 [Information] Found 4 locations
2021-08-17T14:28:00.134 [Information] Built 4 messages
2021-08-17T14:28:00.220 [Information] Executed 'Functions.sendToQueue' (Succeeded, Id=f41c233f-42c9-4da6-ac8a-f354d04be0df, Duration=209ms)
2021-08-17T14:28:00.490 [Information] Found 4 locations
2021-08-17T14:28:00.490 [Information] Built 4 messages
2021-08-17T14:28:00.554 [Information] Executed 'Functions.sendToQueue' (Succeeded, Id=3b0a8941-604e-45b4-839b-33eb5e467751, Duration=542ms)
```

However the Portal Monitor under Invocations reports only one invocation every two minutes. Even though that log shows the timer seeming to fire twice (fracctions of a second apart).

Comment: Do you have multiple app slots running that both point towards the same data source and queue?

Comment: Not really. More clearly, I have a production slot that has this function, but the prod version does not use the queue. And I have a variation of that same function in a stage slow, but the state slot is the only thing using the queue (brand new queue). Also prod runs once a week and the stage function runs once every two minutes (for troubleshooting for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, @bjorne got me looking in the right direction!

Because of a deployment error, this revised function that uses a queue was indeed running in both slots and not just in the stg slot.

What's super frustrating for me is that while I was looking at the monitor log stream for the stg slot in the portal, *that log stream was showing me invocations from both slots*! So it looked the whole time like this was coming from the stg slot.

So hopefully this helps someone avoid a rabbit trail; if you are using slots and seeing double invocations or double results, check out all of your slots and don't necessarily trust an individual slot's logging.

**UPDATE:** I believe that seeing logs from both slots is because both slots had an identical `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` application setting. This is what caused my code to unexpectedly be deployed “in both places” and it also appears that the logging problem goes away when each slot has a distinct `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` application setting.

**UPDATE 2:** Unfortunately this is not yet a complete answer. Setting `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` manually per slot does solve the problem, but then slot swapping doesn't not work as expected. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36458) with someone from Microsoft acknowledging the problem and confirming that it's still not really working correctly. So, this *does* work as desccribed, but you can't use slot swapping.

**UPDATE 3:** Setting `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` manually per slot works. Just make sure the slot name is random (e.g. `my-function-app-0a1b2c3d`). The way slots are named automatically in the portal seems to be `[function-app-name]-[random-8-char-hex-value]`, so copying this seems good. When in doubt, I'd recommend blowing away the old slot and making a new one.